# Map of 64 Tags from Physics.SE

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion

I've just made a map of tags for **Physics.SE**.

In short: tag size is related to tag popularity and edges are related to tag co-occurrences in questions.

For me it looks as a "snapshot" of topics and scope of this SE site. So if you want to you it in any way to promote Physics.SE - feel free!

Also, if you have comments how to improve its usefulness or niceness to our community, I would appreciate them (but bear in mind that I have no color esthetics).

[image: Tag Map for Physics.SE]

### Links:

- [An entry for StackExchange vis competition at Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow/prospector#211) (please vote if you like it :), it ends on Nov 3)
- [Recipe, code and images at GitHub](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange) (e.g. tweak the plot to your taste; feel invited to co-develop)

Comment: Nice :-) I might use it in a (personal) blog post later this month to promote your work and the site.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Nice to hear that! :) So just let me know (e.g. "+" in G+) when it happens.

Comment: This is a cool representation of our community and it would make a good motive for a T-shirt :-) Can it be made dynamic such that it automatically adaptes the size and the links among the tags to include the newly incoming questions?

Comment: @Dilaton Dynamic version (most likely with http://d3js.org + [SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)) is in my plans. However - depending on my energy & time, it may be sooner or later. But remember that dynamic, interactive plots may have some compatibility issues with T-Shirts ;).

Comment: I like it a lot. Now what I want to add is some way to overlay a particular user's footprint (assuming the data can be obtained) - are they more of a particle physicist or a cosmologist? Maybe I'll play with the code. Odds of success: $\sim\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ha ha @ChrisWhite :-D, I thought about a similar idea about having the possibility to let each user draw such a diagram for the tags he uses (with the size given by # each tag is used or the points obtained from it). I personally should probably better refrain from using it, if such a feature existed, because it would make me look like a really really really bad geek :-P

Comment: Entropy being exactly in the middle, that doesn't make sense ;)

Comment: @Chris not too hard to do that, in fact. If you look at the instructions on github, you first have to download a CSV of a certain data.SE query. It's not too hard to fork the query and add a `WHERE P.OwnerUserId=##UserId##` clause in a few places. I've tried it out, see http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/84235/my-observed-to-expected-ratio-o-e-for-tag-pairs-for-n-most-popular-tags. Just use the CSV from that and follo the rest of the procedure.

Comment: @Manishearth Just a small warning - here statistics matters. That is, I plotted 64 tags for the whole physics.SE, as for 128 tags there was too much noise (e.g. edges for only 1 co-occurrence). Instead, I was thinking about making a heat-map over the full graph. Anyway - did you try plotting it for any particular user?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Not yet, I've not got access to my Ubuntu laptop atm. I'll try it later, and I'll edit the query to take care of the 64-tag restriction.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: How did you get them grouped like that? Is there some procedure? TH one on the GH README isn't doing the trick..

Comment: @Manishearth You mean - colored or positioned? (And what's "TH"?)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Colored AND positioned. The Phys.SE one is pretty, I can't manage to make it that pretty for chem and Linguistics :\ And the grouping is meaningful (it looks meaningful, at any rate), so that helps. "TH" was me mistyping "The" :P (and GH=GitHub)

Comment: @Manishearth Strange, it is there `Layout -> ARF -> Run` for an example Layout (you can try others), `Statistics -> Modularity -> Run` then 
`Partition -> Nodes -> Refresh -> Modularity Class -> Apply` are for the coloring. Which part isn't working for you (I know that the Gephi UI is not the intuitive or even logical).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: I don't have ARF under there :/ Also, I only get "weight" when I do Partition->nodes->refresh. I'm using Gephi 0.8.1beta on Ubuntu. Maybe I ought to try the Windows vesion?

Comment: @Manishearth I think that ARF is a plugin you need to install separately (via plugin manager). Before `Partition->Nodes` you need to run `Statistics -> Modularity`. (BTW: I think it is for a chat, not for comments. BTW2: I'm working on MacOSX, but no idea about differences.)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: kk, will do. (I did run Stats>Modularity first). It's a Java app, so it probably won't be different. Btw, technically long discussions are allowed on meta. Anyway, I'll get back to you if I have any troubles, thanks! :)

Comment: Can you post an actual update of the map for the 64 most important tags (in an answer for example) and maybe some kind of a "difference plot" between the most important topics now and back at November 1 2012? I suspect things have changed quite a lot and I'd  like to compare the two snapshots to see the differences.

Comment: @Dilaton Not anytime soon (but code is there so you can, and you are invited, do it for yourself :)). But such type of plots it's not very suitable for seeing differences (also: I don't suspect drastic changes in tag correlations). If you just care about tag popularity, it's simpler to track just tag popularity; anyway, maybe one day I will create automatic plots, but not now...

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I dont expect significant changes in the tag correlations either, but I suspect that when redrawing the plot today, the circles of the two tag groups with the color of quantum-field-theory and general-relativity would be much smaller. I got the impression that the popularity of these two groups of topics is rapidly fading away since the first graph was plotted back in November 2012, and I'd like to test by an appropriate graphical representation of the relevant data if this is objectively true.

Comment: @Dilaton Anyway, to get graph I need to use _all_ data,  data from 3 months would not suffice for correlations (but very likely is perfectly enough for just graph counts). BTW: If you just want to see tag popularity over time, it's enough to use http://data.stackexchange.com/. E.g. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/83404/count-number-of-tags plus a filter on post dates.

Answer (score 3):

I find it weird that QM is all alone in that corner there. Are there really so many QM-QI links to dwarf, say the QM-photons, light, QFT, etc., edges?

Comment: Is short - links are only for very specific connections. If a given topic os connected with many things, but roughly in the same way, then there are not many links from it. It's an effect of taking $P(\text{tag1}\cap\text{tag2})/[P(\text{tag1})P(\text{tag2})]$ as measure of being connected. See also discussions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/a-graph-map-of-math-se) on "homework" and "linear algebra". 

Otherwise it would be hard to plot it (tried, failed) as some topics would be connected to almost everything (e.g. quantum mechanics) while many other - to nothing.